# Eclpse CDT gtest setup error:cannot find -lgtest

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, googletest, googlemock

I follow this [post](http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2011/04/eclipse-cdt-and-google-gtest.html)

to setup gtest 1.7 on eclipse cdt 8.2.1.but got this errors:

```
....test/AllTests.bc src/Test.bc -lgmock -lgtest -lpthread -lstdc++ 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmock
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Info: Parallel threads used: 3
```

By the way,there is some change from gtest 1.5 to 1.7,I actually make link like this:

```
   sudo ln -s lib/.libs/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest.a
```

As you can see,libgtest is under gtest1.7/lib/.lib(the second hidden dir) not gtest1.7/lib.
so what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have attempted to make symbolic links to `libgtest.a`
and `libgmock.a` by using the commands:

```
sudo ln -s lib/.libs/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest.a
sudo ln -s lib/.libs/libgmock.a /usr/lib/libgmock.a
```

from the console in `/your/path/to/gtest-1.7.0` and `/your/path/to/gmock-1.7.0`
respectively.

If you open `/usr/lib` in your file manager, find the links `libgtest.a`
and `libgmock.a` and exam their properties, I believe you will find that
these links are broken, and that is why the linker cannot find them
in your project. Your `ln` commands give relative paths to their targets,
but absolute paths are needed.

If so, delete the broken links and recreate them with the commands:

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.a /usr/lib/libgtest.a
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/mock-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgmock.a /usr/lib/libgmock.a
```

E.g on my system `/full/path/to/` = `/home/imk/develop/`

Then I think your build will work.

However, creating these symbolic links in `/usr/lib` slightly taints your
system installation. It would be better to create them in `/usr/local/lib`.
Or even simpler, you can just add these static libraries to the object files
for your project linkage:

- In Eclipse, navigate ***your project*** -> **Properties** -> **C/C++ build**
  -> **Settings** -> ***your compiler* Linker** -> **Libraries** and delete `gmock.a`, `gtest.a`
- Immediately under **Libraries** you find **Miscellaneous**. There, in
  **Other objects**, add:

  /full/path/to/libgtest.a

  /full/path/to/libgmock.a

All these suggestions have worked for me.